# Server side account creation error

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I have been trying to get server side account user creating to work but I have come across an issue with the check() method I am using server side. (I am using simple-schema for this)

When the password is empty, this causes check() to throw an error, and rightly so. However, this is a server-side error and I am not quite sure how to propagate this to the client to be caught and dealth with.

The exception that I can see from my browser console is as follows:

```
Exception while simulating the effect of invoking 'createUserAccount' Meteor.makeErrorType.errorClass {message: "Match error: One or more properties do not match the schema.", path: "", sanitizedError: Meteor.makeErrorType.errorClass, errorType: "Match.Error", stack: (...)…} Error: Match error: One or more properties do not match the schema.
at SimpleSchema.condition (http://localhost:3000/packages/aldeed_simple-schema.js?8fda161c43c0ba62801a10b0dfcc3eab75c6db88:2450:11)
at checkSubtree (http://localhost:3000/packages/check.js?ac81167b8513b85b926c167bba423981b0c4cf9c:255:17)
at check (http://localhost:3000/packages/check.js?ac81167b8513b85b926c167bba423981b0c4cf9c:67:5)
at Meteor.methods.createUserAccount (http://localhost:3000/both/methods/accounts.js?c418120e76666f0ca774a281caafc39bc2c3a59d:4:27)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?41b62dcceb3ce0de6ca79c6aed088cccde6a44d8:4244:25
at _.extend.withValue (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?81e2f06cff198adaa81b3bc09fc4f3728b7370ec:949:17)
at _.extend.apply (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?41b62dcceb3ce0de6ca79c6aed088cccde6a44d8:4235:54)
at _.extend.call (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?41b62dcceb3ce0de6ca79c6aed088cccde6a44d8:4113:17)
at Object.Template.PasswordRegister.events.submit form (http://localhost:3000/client/views/shared/accounts/accounts.js?ac573d92938a2b3d6107ea19e50065f7ac5d41b3:36:20)
at null. (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:3147:18)
```

Here is how my client code looks like :

```js
Template.PasswordRegister.events({
  'submit form': function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var user = {
      email: template.find('#email').value,
      password: template.find('#password').value
    };

    Meteor.call('createUserAccount', user, function(error) {
      if (error) {
        console.log("CONSOLE : " + error);
        //TODO DO SOMETHING
        // return alert(error.reason);
      } else {
        Meteor.loginWithPassword(user.email, user.password, function(error) {
          if (error) {
            console.log("CONSOLE : " + error);
            //TODO DO SOMETHING
            // return alert(error.reason);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

and here is my server side code:

```js
Meteor.methods({
  createUserAccount: function(user) {
    // Important server-side check for security and data integrity
    check(user, Schema.registration);

    var email = user.email;
    var password = user.password;

    this.unblock();

    return Accounts.createUser({
      email: email,
      password: password
    });
  }
});
```

I've tried wrapping client-side code with a normal try catch block but didn't make any difference; that console error still shows.

Comment: This seems an odd way to do it. Why not use `Accounts.createUser` from the client side? You log in straight after the user is created & you get any errors in the callbacks. You can also use Accounts.validateNewUser ( http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_validatenewuser) to check any fields if thats what you want to do

Comment: I'll probably go down this route for the time being, but this does not fix the issue I have with server side exceptions.

Lets say I have another functionality that needs to levarage check(input, schema) I am still going to come across this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, you have a method stub for 'createUserAccount' defined on the client. It is that client stub that is throwing the exception.

Wrap the method shown with `if (Meteor.isServer)` to keep it from running on the client.

```
if (Meteor.isServer ){
  Meteor.methods({
    createUserAccount: function (user) { ... }
  });
}
```

If that doesn't work search your project for the client code defining the method stub.

To clarify what is happening I have made [a meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/sffj5kn6ysR2Tq2Bx/errorCatch) with a method incorrectly stubbed on the client that throws the error you see in the browser console.  I have then added a second method, 'creatUserAccount1', which is only defined on server.  When this second method is called,  its error is handled by callback and does not cause an exception.  I think that is the behaviour you want.

Comment: This indeed seems to have been the issue!

I had my method in the /both folder rather than the /server!